# How do I determine what version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux my server is running?

Tags: redhat

I can use `uname` and `cat /proc/version` but all I get is the kernel version.

How do I know whether I'm running RHEL4 or 5.5 or such?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can find out in the file /etc/issue

```
cat /etc/issue
```

And also on redhat based systems, you can find out in /etc/redhat-release

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

Comment: I should add that `lsb_release -a` can work for modern versions of Red Hat, Debian, and Ubuntu

Comment: There were no `/etc/issue` or `/etc/redhat-release` files on the redhat server I wanted to interrogate.

Answer (score 8):

`cat /etc/redhat-release` will tell you.

Answer (score 5):

/etc/redhat-release is the usual way, but be careful if you are working on an unfamiliar server. Administrators have been known to "tweak" redhat-release to permit certain software packages requiring Redhat Enterprise to install on similar distributions which are not officially supported by the vendor. For example, IBM's Lotus Domino package typically looks for RHEL before allowing the installer to run, but it can be installed on CentOS by "faking out" the string in /etc/redhat-release.

Answer (score 5):

`rpm -q --whatprovides /etc/redhat-release` can also be used (and it works on both RedHat and CentOS). The version portion of the output should be the OS version.

e.g. An output of "redhat-release-5Server-5.4.0.3" shows that the box is running RHEL 5.4 while "centos-release-5-5.el5.centos" indicates that the box is running CentOS 5.5.

Answer (score 3):

cat /etc/redhat-release

Answer (score -1):

`$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)`